# AntiForgeryToken With Jquery Ajax Calls Using ViewModels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, antiforgerytoken

I have read through here about getting the AntiForgeryToken working with Jquery ajax reuests and I basically have to make sure I include the token with my post/ajax call using something like

```
data: { 
        "__RequestVerificationToken":
        $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val() 
    },
```

However... I am using ViewModels and creating my view model object, assigning my values and then JSON.stringify'ing it and passing it as the data (As per below)

```
        // Ajax call here
    // Make a view model instance
    var ajaxEditPermissionViewModel = new Object();
    ajaxEditPermissionViewModel.HasPermission = isChecked;
    ajaxEditPermissionViewModel.Permission = permission;
    ajaxEditPermissionViewModel.Category = category;
    ajaxEditPermissionViewModel.MembershipRole = role;

    // Ajax call to post the view model to the controller
    var strung = JSON.stringify(ajaxEditPermissionViewModel);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/Permissions/UpdatePermission',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: strung,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            ResetTableAfterAjaxCall();
            ShowSuccessNotification();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            ShowUserMessage("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
            ResetTableAfterAjaxCall();
        }
    });
```

I'm a bit confused how I would pass the token in using my current setup?? Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you feel the need to stringify your result?  We just do this..

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            permission: Permission, 
            // other fields
        }...
```

See this article for how to pass your token using this way of passing parameters:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx

Comment: I did read that the token isn't needed if you are posting JSON? Does that sound correct to you?